# References about automorphism group of a smooth projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

We work over the field of complex numbers.
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety such that $\operatorname{Pic}(X)\simeq \mathbb Z$. Suppose that $X$ admits a non trivial $\mathbb C^*$-action, that is a map
$$
\beta: \mathbb C^* \times X \to X
$$
or equivalently a map
$$
\beta: \mathbb C^* \to \operatorname{Aut}(X)=:G.
$$
What can we say about the properties of $G$?

**Edit.** If we suppose that $X$ is Fano, then $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is a linear algebraic group.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect, apart from $G\supset \mathbb{C}^*$?

Comment: @abx: Is the proof of $\mathbb C^* \subset G$ straightforward? Because I cannot see one. Then, once I know that $\mathbb C^* \subset G$, can we say anything else about $G$? For example, under which hypothesis is $G$ reductive?

Comment: Question 1: I was assuming that your action is algebraic. If it is, the map $\mathbb{C}^*\rightarrow G^{\rm o}$ is a homomorphism of algebraic groups, its image is a (nontrivial) quotient of $\mathbb{C}^*$, hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*$ (if you only assume that the action is holomorphic, the image could be an elliptic curve).

Question 2: I don't know any reasonable hypothesis which implies $G$ reductive.

Comment: Please say any further information you have in your situation.  With the information given, the only result that I can think of is the following.  If $h^0(X,T_X)$ equals $1$, then the image of $\beta$ has finite index in $\text{Aut}^0(X)$.  Thus $\text{Aut}^0(X)$ is reductive.